# Reproduce this scheme with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm new to Tikz and I've already made a few diagrams. However, I'm having trouble making this one. Would it be possible to help me?

It doesn't matter if the colours aren't right, I'm just trying to draw the central block and the two arrows marked "seuils...".

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you have some code to start with? Should this be done just with Ti*k*Z or with PGFPlots?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a very inflexible solution with TikZ using the `chains` library and a `weird` placement rule which needs you to measure the height of the `Niveau` nodes beforehand. (That means that the actual nodes need to have that text and no changes to their `inner ysep`.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  >=Triangle, outer sep=auto, start chain=going weird,
  weird/.style args={of #1}{
    at=(#1.north), shift=(45:\Niveau), anchor=south},
  every on chain/.style={
    rectangle, rotate=-45, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm},
  Niveau node/.style={fill=magenta, text =white, minimum width=3cm},
  Niveau/.style={
    path only,
    to path={-- node[Niveau node, rotate=-45](niv-#1){Niveau #1} (\tikztotarget)}},
]
\sffamily
\begin{scope}
\clip[overlay] (0,0) rectangle (50,50);
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\Niveau{height("Niveau 0")+2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}}
\foreach[
  count=\i from 0,
  evaluate={
    \tc=\i>2?"white":".";
    \fc=int(100*\i/5+15);
  },
  ] \t in {Exclusion, Inclusion, Apprenant, Contributeur, Challenger}
  \node at (1,1) [on chain, fill/.expanded=purple!50!blue!\fc!pink,
                  label={[text=\tc]center:\bfseries\t}, join=by {Niveau=\i}] {};
\end{scope}
\draw[node font=\scshape, <->,very thick] (0,10)
  |- node[near start, rotate=90, above] {Respect}
     node[near end,              below] {Permission} (12,0);

\foreach \niv/\t in {1/Seuil d'inclusion, 4/Seuil d'innovation}
  \path[color={rgb,255:red,70;green,140;blue,180}]
    node[draw, fill, circle, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+1ex]at(niv-\niv.east){}
    edge[thick] node[at end, mid right]{\t} (\tikzlastnode -| 9,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Whahou ! Amazing, that's exactly what I expected. Thank you very much, I will learn a lot with your code.

Comment: it works in a standalone documentclass but not in a book. Do you know why ?

Comment: @BenoîtDarroux You need to load `\usepackage{tikz}` in a `book`. This is done here by the `standalone` class.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirbel, I found the issue (I already used tikz package), it's because I use \usepackage[french]{babel}.
I don't know how it impacts, it seems linked to the \fc command.

Comment: You will need to load `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` then.